# Erro no update "Call to undefined function mysqli_sql()"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

Ao realizar o *update* é me retornado o seguinte erro no 1º resultado:

### Erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_sql() in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\PAPBRUNO\PAPBRUNO\alterar_cli_exe.php on line 21

### Meu código:

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_calcadocharme");

    $user = $_POST['user'];

    if((isset($_POST['nome'])) && ($_POST['nome'] != "")){
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes SET nome='$nome'  WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$nome</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }


    if((isset($_POST['rua'])) && ($_POST['rua'] != "")){
            $rua = $_POST['rua'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set morada='$rua' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$Rua</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }



    if((isset($_POST['Data'])) && ($_POST['Data'] != "")){
            $Data = $_POST['Data'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set datanasc='$Data' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$data_nasc</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }

    if((isset($_POST['sexo'])) && ($_POST['sexo'] != "")){
            $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set sexo='$sexo' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$sexo</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }

    if((isset($_POST['escolher'])) && ($_POST['escolher'] != "")){
            $pais = $_POST['escolher'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set pais='$pais' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$pais</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }    

    if((isset($_POST['cidade'])) && ($_POST['cidade'] != "")){
            $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set cidade='$cidade' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$cidade</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }  


    if((isset($_POST['telemovel'])) && ($_POST['telemovel'] != "")){
            $tele = $_POST['telemovel'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set telemovel='$tele' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$tele</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }


    if((isset($_POST['user'])) && ($_POST['user'] != "")){
            $user = $_POST['user'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set user='$user' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$user</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }


    if((isset($_POST['pass'])) && ($_POST['pass'] != "")){
            $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql="UPDATE clientes set senha='$password' WHERE user=$user";
    $result = mysqli_sql ($link ,  $sql);
    echo "O Preço foi alterado para : <b>$password</b>€.";
    echo"<br><br>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando uma função inexistente `mysqli_sql()`. A função que você deveria usar é `mysqli_query()`, a [**documentação do php**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) mostra o uso correto desta função.

Portanto substitua todos os `mysqli_sql()` por `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Obrigado, erro resolvido, mas nao entendo o porque de nao alterar na base de dados, não altera mesmo nada

Comment: O *update* funciona corretamente no console do *mysql*?

Comment: A coluna `user` é do tipo `int` ou `varchar`? @Odacil

Comment: é do tipo varchar

Comment: Tem como postar o `sql` de saída depois do *php* ser executado?